# Select row which contains exact number in column with set of numbers separated by comma

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Maybe answer is very easy, but I can't find the right MySQL query which do what I want.

I have table **user** :

```
| id_user |  name   | action_type |
+---------------------------------+
|    1    | joshua  |  1,13,12,40 |
|    2    | joshua  |  2,8        |
```

And I want to select only rows which have exact number in `action_type` column.

`action_type` is stored in MySQL as TEXT.

I've tried this:

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE action_type LIKE '%2%'`

But it selected rows with 12 which is not what I want :(

Maybe it's possible with IN operator, but I couldn't find a right way to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '2', action_type )
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0023b/1/0)

**UPDATE**

Just to mentioned it, this is also possible

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 2, action_type )
```

MySQL will do an automatic conversion to char

Answer (score 2):

Include the delimiter in your `LIKE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM   user
WHERE  action_type LIKE '2,%'
        OR action_type LIKE '%,2,%'
        OR action_type LIKE '%,2'
```

Note that I had to use two additional `LIKE` clauses to cover the cases where the item is at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Asad your solution really works :) Thank you alot. And it is possible with IN statement instead LIKE, or its nonsense?

Comment: FIND_IN_SET thats the use case for it ;o)

Comment: @user1912080 While this approach works, `FIND_IN_SET` is a much more elegant solution. You might consider acccepting Rufo's answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE CONCAT( ',', action_type, ',' ) LIKE '%,2,%';
```

- correct syntax from Sir Rufo

Comment: Thanks - I'd tried it in Sql Server.  Amended to work in MySQL as per OP's request.  Edit:  Didn't work in Sql Server with text column either.  I should read the question properly!